# How to color render a checked combobox component in table in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I have a ComboBox which contains checkbox inside it, placed in a table. Whenever I select the row, the color render is applying only to remaining cells of the table. How to render the "checkedcombobox", so that it can also get selection color matching with other cells in the row of a table.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for you:

```
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI;

public class TableEditorExample {

    private static final String[] COLS = {"Number", "Type", "Name"};

    private static final Object[][] DATA = {{"1", "Book", "Brave new world"}, {"2", "Music", "Smells like a teen spirit"},
            {"3", "Film", "Star Wars"}};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Nothing
        }
        JFrame frm = new JFrame("Test combo renderer");
        JTable tbl = new JTable(DATA, COLS);
        tbl.setRowHeight(20);
        JComboBox<String> combo = new JComboBox<>(new String[] {"Book", "Music", "Film"});
        combo.setUI(new BasicComboBoxUI());
        combo.setBackground(tbl.getSelectionBackground());
        combo.setForeground(tbl.getSelectionForeground());
        tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(combo));
        frm.add(new JScrollPane(tbl));
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.pack();
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

So, what you need to do is:

```
combo.setUI(new BasicComboBoxUI());
combo.setBackground(tbl.getSelectionBackground());
combo.setForeground(tbl.getSelectionForeground());
```

Here is the screenshot of the corresponded program (for Windows):
[image: Table example]

Comment: Hi Sergiy, If I have only combo box , can able to render it perfectly. The problem I'm facing here is, I've check box implemented inside combo box and also label to show how many checkbox values selected on top of it.

Comment: @GouruNagaraju Hi. Please provide a runnable code example, so I can also reproduce and debug your problem.